# Where is the Windows 8 Challenge Achievements bar?

Tags: bug, status-completed, windows-8-challenge

There used to be a sort of "Achievements Bar" for the Windows 8 Challenge on your User page. But as of a few hours ago, it is gone. What happened?

Comment: Hmm I'm seeing that it disappeared, too. I've forwarded this up the chain; hopefully somebody will take a look at it soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's back now!

We had temporarily disabled the [Win8Challenge](http://win8challenge.com/) banners and user page widgets as we performed maintenance on some of our [new machines in Oregon](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/10/30/failing-over-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-for-sandy/).

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response!